# Determine if a particular matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

my teacher gave me this exercise:
Determine if this matrix is diagonalizable
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1&1&1\\ 
1&2&3&4\\ 
1&-1&2&-2\\ 
0&0&1&-2 
\end{pmatrix}
$

I have tried to calculate the characteristic polynomial, that is $-13 + 10 x + x^2 - 3 x^3 + x^4$, but I don't know how to go on. 
I tried to look at the roots of the characteristic polynomial with Wolfram Alpha and they are horrible! So I think that must exist an alternative way to do it!
Have you got any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You should have seen at least one theorem of the form: A real square matrix is diagonalisable if and only if . . . Do you remember any such theorems?

Comment: Are you sure that you have jotted down the matrix correctly? It seems to me that the third row should be $(1,-2,-2,-2)$ instead of $(1,-1,2,-2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The matrix is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb C$) if, and only if, it has 'four' eigenvalues. In particular, if the matrix has four distinct eigenvalues, then it is diagonalizable. Using the characteristic polynomial, can you prove that the matrix has four distinct eigenvalues?

**Further hints:** Recall that given a polynomial function $P$ whose coefficients are all real, it holds  that $\forall z\in \mathbb C\left(P(z)=0\implies P(\overline z)=0\right)$. Since the characteristic polynomial is a real fourth (even!) degree polynomial, either all roots are non-real, there exactly 'two' (beware of multiplicities) real roots or all roots are real. Use the *intermediate value theorem* theorem to prove that there are at least two real roots and check the derivative to prove that there are no more than two real roots.

Comment: I know this theorem, but the roots of this polynomial are $\textbf{horrible}$. So either my teacher is a sadist either there is a better solution.

Comment: @user3343783 My point is that you don't need to find the roots, it suffices to prove that four distinct roots exist.

Comment: I am not able, can you show me how you do it please?

Comment: @user3343783 See the edit.

Comment: @GitGud The polynomial $x^3(x-1)$ has two real roots, namely $x=0$ and $x=1$ and so satisfies the condition of having at least two real roots. Yet not all roots are distinct

Comment: @FlybyNight I agree. Are you claiming my answer is wrong somewhere? If so, where? **Edit:** I think I know what you mean, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Showing that a quartic has at least two real roots does not show that all of its roots are distinct. Your guarantee that all roots are distinct is false and a "proof" based on it would be equally unsound.

Comment: @FlybyNight Thank you. Fixed it.

Comment: @Git In order to prove that the complex roots are distinct, do you have any other method than computing $gcd(P,P')$ ?

Comment: @G.T.R Yes, I'm alluding to it in my answer. It follows from this $\forall z\in \mathbb C\left(P(z)=0\implies P(\overline z)=0\right)$. Can you see it? **Edit:** I'm interpreting 'complex' as 'non-real'.

Comment: @Git ah, multiplicity two would imply $z=\bar{z}$, contradicting $z$ is not real. Nice !

Comment: @G.T.R It certainly can have multiplicity two ($(x^2+1)^2$). I'm not saying your reasoning is wrong in this case, but let me clarify. Here the non-real roots are necessarily all distinct because there are at least two real roots (this can be checked with calculus) and it is a fourth degree polynomial, so there is only room for two more roots. But if $\alpha\in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$ is a root, so is $\overline \alpha$, making it four roots.

Answer (score 1):

If the roots of the characteristic polynomial are distinct, the matrix is diagonalizable (the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) is composed of $1\times1$ [Jordan blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_block)). The roots of the polynomial $P$ are distinct if $\deg(\gcd(P,P'))=0$ (if $(x-a)^n$ divides $P$, then $(x-a)^{n-1}$ divides $P'$).

Using the [Polynomial Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomial_extended_Euclidean_algorithm) on $\color{#C00000}{P}$ and $\color{#00A000}{P'}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&(1822x^3-1987x^2-2613x+10903)(\color{#00A000}{4x^3-9x^2+2x+10})\\
&-(7288x^2-2482x-3659)(\color{#C00000}{x^4-3x^3+x^2+10x-13})\\
&=61463
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\deg(\gcd(P,P'))=0$, and therefore, the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?